# upload stopped with errors wjhk.jupload2.policies.DefaultUploadpolicy.checkUploadSuccess()

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I am using jupload applet in my JSP. When i try to upload i am getting this error:

```
upload stopped with errors wjhk.jupload2.policies.DefaultUploadpolicy.checkUploadSuccess()
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was it was not able to create a temp folder in c... when i created manually it worked fine...thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

http://jupload.sourceforge.net/howto-customization.html

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: its documentation, read it, maybe you'll found something useful